# Как извлечь данные из DragEventArgs?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
    private void listView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.DoDragDrop(listView1.SelectedItems, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }
    void richTextBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {            
        richTextBox1.LoadFile("Тут должен быть мой путь к файлу, данные хранятся в e", System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);

    }
```

Как извлечь данные из `DragEventArgs e`? В `richTextBox` данные перетягиваю из `listView`

Comment: Смотрите свойство `Data`. А как именно - зависит от того, как вы данные туда поместили. Покажите свой код, как вы начинаете DragDrop.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov поправил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как в метод `DoDragDrop` передаётся коллекция `SelectedItems`, имеющая тип `ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection`, то именно этот тип нужно извлекать:

```
private void RichTextBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItems = (ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection)e.Data.GetData(
        typeof(ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection));

    if (selectedItems != null)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in selectedItems)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(item.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание, что это именно *коллекция*. Следовательно, в ней может быть несколько элементов, а не только один. Возможно, вам изначально это не нужно. Тогда передавайте в `DoDragDrop` именно один элемент.